# PostgreSQL getting daily, weekly, and monthly averages of the occurrences of an event in one query

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, aggregate-functions, analytics

Currently I have this rather large query that works by

1. Aggregating the daily, weekly, monthly counts into intermediate tables by taking the `count()` of an event grouped by the event name and the date.
2. Selecting the avg count over each intermediate table by doing `avg()` group by just event, doing a union of the results, and because I want to have a separate column for daily, weekly, monthly, putting a filler value of 0 into empty columns.
3. I then sum over all the columns, and the 0s basically act as a no-op, which gives me just a single value for each event.

---

The query is pretty large though, and I feel like I'm doing a lot of repetitive work. Is there any way to do this query better or make it smaller? I haven't really done queries like this before so I'm not quite sure.

```
WITH monthly_counts as (
  SELECT
    event,
    count(*) as count
  FROM tracking_stuff
  WHERE
    event = 'thing'
    OR event = 'thing2'
    OR event = 'thing3'
  GROUP BY event, date_trunc('month', created_at)
),
weekly_counts as (
  SELECT
    event,
    count(*) as count
  FROM tracking_stuff
  WHERE
    event = 'thing'
    OR event = 'thing2'
    OR event = 'thing3'
  GROUP BY event, date_trunc('week', created_at)
),
daily_counts as (
  SELECT
    event,
    count(*) as count
  FROM tracking_stuff
  WHERE
    event = 'thing'
    OR event = 'thing2'
    OR event = 'thing3'
  GROUP BY event, date_trunc('day', created_at)
),
query as (
  SELECT
    event,
    0 as daily_avg,
    0 as weekly_avg,
    avg(count) as monthly_avg
  FROM monthly_counts
  GROUP BY event
  UNION
  SELECT
    event,
    0 as daily_avg,
    avg(count) as weekly_avg,
    0 as monthly_avg
  FROM weekly_counts
  GROUP BY event
  UNION
  SELECT
    event,
    avg(count) as daily_avg,
    0 as weekly_avg,
    0 as monthly_avg
  FROM daily_counts
  GROUP BY event
)
SELECT
  event,
  sum(daily_avg) as daily_avg,
  sum(weekly_avg) as weekly_avg,
  sum(monthly_avg) as monthly_avg
FROM query
GROUP BY event;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd write the query in a way like this:

```sql
select event, daily_avg, weekly_avg, monthly_avg
from (
    select event, avg(count) monthly_avg
    from (
        select event, count(*)
        from tracking_stuff
        where event in ('thing1', 'thing2', 'thing3')
        group by event, date_trunc('month', created_at)
    ) s
    group by 1
) monthly
join (
    select event, avg(count) weekly_avg
    from (
        select event, count(*)
        from tracking_stuff
        where event in ('thing1', 'thing2', 'thing3')
        group by event, date_trunc('week', created_at)
    ) s
    group by 1
) weekly using(event)
join (
    select event, avg(count) daily_avg
    from (
        select event, count(*)
        from tracking_stuff
        where event in ('thing1', 'thing2', 'thing3')
        group by event, date_trunc('day', created_at)
    ) s
    group by 1
) daily using(event)
order by 1;
```

---

If the `where` condition eliminates a significant portion of the data (say more than a half) the use of `cte` could slightly speed up the query execution:

```sql
with the_data as (
    select event, created_at
    from tracking_stuff
    where event in ('thing1', 'thing2', 'thing3')
    )

select event, daily_avg, weekly_avg, monthly_avg
from (
    select event, avg(count) monthly_avg
    from (
        select event, count(*)
        from the_data
        group by event, date_trunc('month', created_at)
    ) s
    group by 1
) monthly
--  etc ...
```

---

Just out of curiosity, I've done a test on the data:

```sql
create table tracking_stuff (event text, created_at timestamp);
insert into tracking_stuff
    select 'thing' || random_int(9), '2016-01-01'::date+ random_int(365)
    from generate_series(1, 1000000);
```

In every query I've replaced `thing` with `thing1`, so the queries eliminate about 2/3 of rows.

Average execution time of 10 tests:

```
    Original query          1106 ms
    My query without cte    1077 ms
    My query with cte        902 ms
    Clodoaldo's query       5187 ms
```

Comment: Just a real quick question without checking any facts...aren't joins more costly than unions? Also any reason for not using `with` other than preference?

Comment: In this case the difference between `union` and `join` should be imperceptible. A similar remark may involve the use of `cte`. Usually I use `with` when I need recursion.

Comment: a `CTE` is an optimization fence for the planner. Might or not make a difference.

Answer (score 9):

In 9.5+ use [`grouping sets`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS)

> The data selected by the FROM and WHERE clauses is grouped separately by each specified grouping set, aggregates computed for each group just as for simple GROUP BY clauses, and then the results returned

```
select event,
    avg(total) filter (where day is not null) as avg_day,
    avg(total) filter (where week is not null) as avg_week,
    avg(total) filter (where month is not null) as avg_month    
from (
    select
        event,
        date_trunc('day', created_at) as day,
        date_trunc('week', created_at) as week,
        date_trunc('month', created_at) as month,
        count(*) as total
    from tracking_stuff
    where event in ('thing','thing2','thing3')
    group by grouping sets ((event, 2), (event, 3), (event, 4))
) s
group by event
```

To learn more about `grouping sets`, consider these tutorials: [one](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/postgresql-grouping-sets-rollup-cube/), [two](https://yogeshchauhan.com/how-to-use-grouping-sets-to-boost-group-by-queries-in-postgres/)

Comment: This is very interesting hint! Though my intuition tells me this query should be rather expensive.

Comment: It's good to consider @klin's comment here as they are a Postgres expert (and I am a dev who uses Postgres but not an expert like that). Just want to note for other readers that grouping sets can be a performant choice and it depends on the specific query/data. As always, we can use `explain` to look at our specific queries.